# Defining Maven extensions globally (as a GAV)

Tags: maven

I would like to *globally* define the extensions that Maven should use for its execution. This is for a CI scenario. For various reasons I cannot commit `.mvn/extensions.xml` file to each and every repo. (there are too many of them and our extension(s) are only relevant in a CI scenario, not for local development and such extensions doesn't necessarily play well with an IDE).

Let's say I have Maven extension from Central Maven. Said extension has many transitive dependencies that I really don't want to know about. It works well when configured with the in-repo `.mvn/extensions.xml` file.

I know I can do it old-school by setting the `maven.ext.class.path=extension.jar` system property on the command line but that one only works with a JARs. You would really have to do a lot of external work to download transitive dependencies for your extension, resolve clashes with rest of Maven, build classpath string from all those jars, etc. Simply too brittle.

Another tried solution: In the CI pipeline I can copy into my checked out source code a custom `.mvn/extensions.xml` just before Maven executes. However, this makes Git think the repo is dirty so this has other negative implications for our build pipeline.

Surely there must be another way?

Maven version 3.5+